# Create a list of objects from another list using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have these three dto classes :

```
public class OrganismeDTO {
    private Long organismeId;
    private String libelle;
    private List<RoleDTO> rolesDTO;
}

public class RoleDTO {
    private String lib;
    private Long roleId;
    private List<ProfilDTO> profilsDTO;
}

public class UtilisateurRoleDto {
    private String organismeLib;
    private String roleLib;
}
```

And in my `DAO` I have a function that will return a list of `UtilisateurRoleDto`.

What I want, is to create a list of `OrganismeDTO`from `UtilisateurRoleDto` list (Which I can get from my DAO), so for example, if I have a list of `UtilisateurRoleDto` as following:

```
"Organisme 1", "Role 1"
"Organisme 1", "Role 2"
"Organisme 2", "Role 1"
"Organisme 2", "Role 3"
"Organisme 3", "Role 3"
```

I want a list of `OrganismeDTO` in result as following (where each `OrganismeDTO` has a list of `RoleDTO`) :

```
"Organisme 1" : ["Role 1", "Role 2"]
"Organisme 2" : ["Role 1", "Role 3"]
"Organisme 3" : ["Role 3"]
```

How can I implement this using Java 8 streams?

## Update:

When I construct the `RoleDTO` I need to inject `RoleDTO.profilsDTO` by a list I get from a function that takes `OrganismeDTO.roleId` and returns `List<ProfilDTO>`.

Comment: How are `RoleDTO` and `roleLib` similar?

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector

Comment: I think  if you create a map from  UtilisateurRoleDto list then will help you to find the solution.

Comment: @nullpointer I didnt understand your question, in fact, `RoleDTO.lib` is the same as `UtilisateurRoleDto.roleLib`

Comment: @VishnuKR that works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a custom collect(I added getters and some obvious constructors):

```
Map<String, OrganismeDTO> map = dt.stream().collect(HashMap::new, (m, t) -> {
    m.computeIfAbsent(t.getOrganismeLib(), x -> new OrganismeDTO(t.getOrganismeLib())).getRolesDTO().add(new RoleDTO(t.getRoleLib()));
}, (m1, m2) -> {
    m2.forEach((k,v) -> {
        OrganismeDTO organismeDTO = m1.get(k);
        if (organismeDTO != null ) {
            organismeDTO.getRolesDTO().addAll(v.getRolesDTO());
        } else {
            m1.put(k, v);
        }
    });
});
```

And then all that's left if to create `List` from the values.

```
List<OrganismeDTO> list = map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: When I tried this I got a `NullPointerException` in this line : `.add(new RoleDTO(t.getRoleLib())`, is it because getRolesDTO() is not initialized as an ArrayList ?

Comment: @AimadMAJDOU Yes, in my "obvious constructor" I initialize it with an `ArrayList`.

Comment: What I mean is the `getRolesDTO()` will be null since it has to be initialized as a `new ArrayList`, so what I did is: `private List<RoleDTO> rolesDTO = new ArrayList<>();` in the `OrganismeDTO` class and the error is gone.

Comment: This solution is working for me, thanks for your help, it would be great if you could explain the code you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of at the moment is this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> collect = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(UtilisateurRoleDto::getOrganismeLib,
                    Collectors.mapping(UtilisateurRoleDto::getRoleLib, Collectors.toList())));

List<OrganismeDTO> result = collect.entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> new OrganismeDTO(entry.getKey(),
                entry.getValue().stream()
                        .map(RoleDTO::new)
                        .collect(toList())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Firstly you can group your `UtilisateurRoleDto` by it's `organismeLib` field. After that you process the obtained result and map it to your wanted entities.

Comment: Thank you, but I forgot to add the id field for `OrganismeDTO` and `RoleDTO`, could you please recheck my update.

Comment: From where should I get those ``ids`` ? or do I have to generate them randomly ? ...

Comment: They are already defined : `OrganismeDTO.organismeId` and `RoleDTO.roleId`